# How can I search in the greeting fields?

Tags: search, custom-search, search-builder

I would like to do a search in the greeting field for all contacts with the greeting 'Dear%'. Neither with the search builder nor the contact search I was successfull. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the search builder again, select contacts from the include where, pick up Email Greeting and the operator is LIKE dear%

Just tested this on the drupal demo site, and it works.

Comment: Thanks, but hat is exactly what I did, but it doesn't work. The answer ist:
"Keine Treffer gefunden für:
E-Mail-Grußformel LIKE 'dear%'"

but there are a lot of 'dear' in the greetings.

(Is there a possibility to place a screenshot here?)